# Control fmt.Parse output on Parsing Error

Tags: go

```
var timesFlag int  
flag.IntVar(&timesFlag, "times", 1, "Number of times to print")
flag.Parse()
```

If I run the program and type in prog -times=abc  (<--- not an int)

fmt.Parse spits out this ugly error message on the console:

*invalid value "-abc" for flag -times: strconv.ParseInt: parsing "-abc": invalid syntax*

Obviously, I can't prevent the user from typing in anything from the command line. The error looks like garbage to the user and needs to look more friendlier. How do I silent this error from going to stderr/stdout and detect there was an error generated?

Answer (score 1):

The [`flag.CommandLine`](http://golang.org/pkg/flag/#pkg-variables) *variable* of type the [`FlagSet`](http://golang.org/pkg/flag/#FlagSet) is used to handle command line arguments if you use the functions of the `flag` package which are not methods of the `FlagSet` type.

You can set the output (an [`io.Writer`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer)) where error messages are printed with the [`FlagSet.SetOutput()`](http://golang.org/pkg/flag/#FlagSet.SetOutput) method. You can set a [`bytes.Buffer`](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer) so messages will only end up in a buffer (and not on your console). Note that do not set `nil` as that means to print to the standard output (console).

And call [`FlagSet.Parse()`](http://golang.org/pkg/flag/#FlagSet.Parse) yourself where you can pass `os.Args[1:]` as the arguments to be parsed. `FlagSet.Parse()` returns an `error` which you can handle yourself.